# Steps to redirect url of website to wordpress site in sub folder keep same url with IIS server

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis-7

I have searched this thoroughly, but can not fine the solution for IIS 7.

My client has an active website hosted on an IIS 7 server. I have created an WordPress website in a sub-folder of that directory.

Example: clientSite.com   ~   clientSite.com/_dev/

I am looking for the steps to point the entire site to _dev folder, and be fully functional but not have it show the redirect. In other words, the _dev/ never shows in the site path, even though all pages and posts of the site are in the clientSite.com/_dev/ path. Essentially, I need to strip the _dev from ever being seen.

I have seen this done with Apache servers, but have not found anything on IIS server redirect cloaking.

The purpose for doing this is to have the site switched to the dev site until I can change the files and database to the original site url, then turn off the redirect.

You help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770409%28v=ws.10%29) can help you?

> appcmd set config /section:httpRedirect /exactDestination:true | false

Comment: I hope that the page can help.

Comment: Me too @scessor. I will give an update on the results. Thank you again.